# best way to transform a string to array

Tags: php, regex

I have an array `$AR`
I have a string `"set[0][p1]"`

When given this string, I need the best way to access the array at `$AR['set'][0]['p1']`

I have total control on that string, so I need not to worry from injections and stuff, and I can be sure it will be well formatted. There is no way I can put the p1 inside ' to be `"set[0]['p1']"`

Comment: Do you "control" that string? I.e. is it guaranteed to be "well-formed" and not to contain any malicious code?

Comment: This question is actually a rather fascinating one, and I'm totally planning on stealing it to make it an "interview question".

Answer (score 3):

Check [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str('set[0][p1]', $AR);
```

---

Oh, you want to ***access*** the index of the array... Here is my take:

```
getValue($AR, array('set', 0, 'p1'));
```

Or if you really must use the original string representation:

```
parse_str('set[0][p1]', $keys);
getValue($AR, $keys);
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, you might need to use `array_keys()` somewhere.*

---

And the helper function:

```
function getValue($array, $key, $default = false)
{
    if (is_array($array) === true)
    {
        settype($key, 'array');

        foreach ($key as $value)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($value, $array) === false)
            {
                return $default;
            }

            $array = $array[$value];
        }

        return $array;
    }

    return $default;
}
```

I would avoid regexing your way into this problem.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, I just realized that. Sorry! =o

Comment: With the current version the "magic part" would be to get from "set[0][p1]" to array(set,0,p1) if the op wants to stick to the original plan ;)

Comment: `parseString` will give you `Array([set] => Array([0] => Array([p1]=>)))`, not a flat array. I would say the easiest way is to use `preg_split` (like in my answer ;))

Answer (score 3):

My try, which should be able to deal with an arbitrary amount of `[]`s in the string:

To split the string you can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

```
$parts = preg_split('%\[?(\w+)\]?%', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

(More) complete code:

```
function get_value($string, $array) {
    $parts = preg_split('%\[?(\w+)\]?%', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach($parts as $part) {
        $array = $array[$part];
    }

    return $array;
}

$array = array('set'=>array(array('p1'=>'foo')));
$string = "set[0][p1]";

echo get_value($string, $array); // echoes 'foo'
```

I leave the error handling to you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is crazy, but have you considered extract?  It may not be the fastest solution, but it has the novelty of needing minimal code.

```
extract( $AR );
$target = eval("\$set[0]['p1']");
```

The major difference (as far as input is concerned) is that you would need to pre-pend '$' to the string, and make sure that the brackets have quote marks inside.

The major benefit is that it becomes extraordinarily obvious what you're trying to accomplish, and you're using two native PHP functions.  Both of these mean that the solution would be far more "readable" by those unfamiliar with your system.

Oh, and you're only using two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like. I'm not 100% about the "[" and "]" brackets as I've never had to run a regex on them before... if it's wrong can someone correct me??

```
foreach(preg_split('/[\[\]]/', "set[0][p1]") as $aValue) {
    $AR[$aValue[0]][$aValue[1]][$aValue[2]] = '?';
}
```

Comment: Your regex will give this: `Array([0] => set,[1] => 0,[2] =>,[3] => p1,[4] =>)`